# need xpath selector plugin for jquery

Tags: jquery, xpath

i need to be able to select Xpaths in jquery.

selecting via CSS is difficult for form elements with name, value, type, not to mention traversing down the tree.

Comment: How is it difficult? $("form input[type=text]") or $("form :input[name=somename]") etc... See entire forms section at the bottom of http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors

Comment: You may want to try [jQuery XPath plugin with support for XPath 2.0](https://github.com/ilinsky/jquery-xpath) syntax that works cross-browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the name of the element won't this work fine?

```
//by name
$('form input[name="foo"]')

//by id
$('#foo')

//by name in a specific form
$('form[name="bar"] input[name="foo"]')

//3rd option in a select
$('form[name="bar"] select[name="foo"] option:nth-child(3)')
```

Answer (score 3):

jQuery supports basic Xpath by default.

http://docs.jquery.com/DOM/Traversing/Selectors#XPath_Selectors

EDIT- Kevin said it, it's only supported in 1.2, not anymore in 1.3.
Try using advanced CSS selectors, attribute filters: http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors

Comment: jQuery DID support XPATH in the past. It no longer does since v1.2+